# Z3Py - Calling functions written as Z3 expressions

Tags: python, solidity, z3, z3py

I am using Z3Py and I have a function which is written as Z3 expressions in Python, can I call that function in another function?

```
def func1 (a,b,c):
    vara = a * b
    varb = URem (vara, c)
    result = If (vara > 0, varb, 0)
    return result

def func2 (a,b,c):
    var1 = func1 (a,b,c)
    var2 = URem (var1, c)
    result2 = If (var1 > 0, var2, 0)
    return result2
```

The problem i am facing is that if I call a function from another function, in this case calling func1 from func2, i always get UNSAT for some invariant. However, if i copy and paste the complete code at the location of functional call, everything works. So, my question is how does function calling work in Z3Py?

Comment: Please read [ask] and write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title. For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Comment: Please post a minimal complete example. That is, something that we can run, displaying output you got, and how it differs from your expectation.